# Parse JSON from an Array into NSDictionary? (ObjC)

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary, afnetworking

Looking at it for some time now and tried every possible way in my knowledge, but still without any success.

How can I parse the following JSON to get the first array into a dictionary? I am using the AFNetworking library and the responseObject returns the following:

```
(
y,
    (
    yeti,
    "yeti tumbler",
    "yoga pants",
    "yoga mat",
    "yeezy boost 350",
    "yeti cup",
    yoga,
    yeezy,
    "young living essential oils",
    yugioh
),
    (
            {
        nodes =             (
                            {
                alias = garden;
                name = "Home & Kitchen";
            },
                            {
                alias = "outdoor-recreation";
                name = "Outdoor Recreation";
            },
                            {
                alias = "fan-shop";
                name = "Sports Fan Shop";
            }
        );
    },
            {
    },
            {
    },
            {
    },
            {
    },
            {
    },
            {
    },
            {
    },
            {
    },
            {
    }
),
    (
)
```

)

Now, how can I get the first array into a NSDictionary?

```
(
    yeti,
    "yeti tumbler",
    "yoga pants",
    "yoga mat",
    "yeezy boost 350",
    "yeti cup",
    yoga,
    yeezy,
    "young living essential oils",
    yugioh
)
```

ObjC code:

```
    - (void)requestJSONWithQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    if (!_requestOperation.isCancelled) [_requestOperation cancel];
    query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:_URLDictionaryForAPIs[@(_APIType)], query];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    _requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    _requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    __block FFFGoogleSearchAutoCompleteController *selfInBlock = self;
    [_requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


     //   NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        selfInBlock.suggestions = [(NSDictionary *)responseObject mutableArrayValueForKey:query];
        [selfInBlock refreshSuggestionTable];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


    }];
    [_requestOperation start];
}
```

This will return the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSTaggedPointerString 0xa0000000000006b1> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key K.'
```

Comment: What format do you want the dictionary to have?  What are your objects?  What are your keys?

Comment: what is the value of `query`? And what does the `responseObject` print? By the look of your first print of `responseObject` it looks like a multidimensional array.

Comment: responseObject prints the first codeblock in my post above. Value of the query is the inserted text. The JSON file looks like: http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=k

Comment: What the key and value you want in dictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`["k",["kindle","kindle fire","kindle books","keurig","knife","kate spade","keyboard","kindle paperwhite","knife sharpener","kindle fire case"],[{"nodes":[{"name":"Kindle Store","alias":"digital-text"},{"name":"Electronics","alias":"electronics"},{"name":"Computers","alias":"computers"}]},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[]]`

is not a dictionary. Your response is an array. The first item is the query. The second seems to be the thing that you want. I would try to do this for a test:

`selfInBlock.suggestions = [(NSArray *)responseObject  objectAtIndex:1];`

Comment: You saved the day! Thanks a million! Of course it should be the second object.